# Публикации проекта через ClickOnce

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

опубликовал локально проект. После этого установил его через setup. При запуске ничего не происходит. Приложение `WPF .Net Fraemwork 4.7.2` Приложение спокойно запускается через exe в папке Release.
Попробовал пересоздать проект и заново импортировать либы. Не помогло.
Из-за чего это может происходить?